# Поиск по части элемента в массиве и вывод элемента (Python)

Tags: python

Имеется файл, в котором порядка тысячи строк. Для быстроты поиска я сперва помещаю его в массив (пока тестирую, не уверен, что так на самом деле быстрее). В общем, мне нужно, чтоб при нахождении строки, содержащей слово, выводилась вся строка. Попытался реализовать вот так, но выводится последняя строка из файла. И я не очень понимаю, как мне получить нужную строку?

```
list = []
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    list.append(line)

def searchlist(word):
    if any(word in line for line in list):
        print('Your word is in this line:')
        print(line)
    else:
        print('There is no lines with your word')

while True:
    word = input('Input word to find:')
    searchlist(word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо этого:

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    list.append(line)
```

используйте это:

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
list = f.readlines()
```

и кстати называть переменные ключевыми словами не очень хорошо (в смысле плохо)

последняя строка выводится, потому что

```
if any(word in line for line in list):
```

определяет СНАЧАЛА есть ли слово во всех строках, поэтому если слово есть, то вы получаете последнее значение `line` из цикла, т.е. последнюю строку в списке

итого ваш код должен быть таким:

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

is_found = False

for line in f.readlines():
    if word in line:
        is_found = True
        print('Your word is in this line:', line)

if not is_found:
    print('There is no lines with your word')

f.close()
```

или можно сделать чуть покрасивее:

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

found = [line[:-1] for line in f.readlines() if word in line]

if len(found):
    print('Your word is in this line:')
    print(*found, sep='\n')
else:
    print('There is no lines with your word')

f.close()
```

**P.S.**

и самое главное `word in text` ищет не слово, в тексте, а часть текста, например `"xxy" in "xxyxx"` найдет вхождение текста

так что по хорошему это тоже надо бы учесть

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли разобраться. По поводу уточнения, мне именно так и надо, чтоб искало часть текста.